# Настройка Slick слайдера

Tags: javascript, jquery, вёрстка, slider, slick.js

Мне нужно настроить slick slider таким образом, чтобы  он автоматически прокручивался до последнего слайдера и там останавливался. Сейчас он прокручивается до последнего, и цикл прокрутки начинается заново. Вот код:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.slider').slick({
            dots: true,
            speed: 300,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplaySpeed: 2500,
            infinite: false
          });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
let qtySlides = $('.slider>div').length-1;
 let slider=$('.slider').slick({
            dots: true,
            speed: 300,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplaySpeed: 2500,
            infinite: false
          });
 slider.on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
   if( qtySlides === slider.slick('slickCurrentSlide') ){
     slider.slickSetOption("autoplay",false,false)
   };
 });
```

Comment: сработало, спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slider').slick({
        dots: true,
        speed: 300,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 2500,
        infinite: false,
        onAfterChange: function(slide, index) {
            if(index == 4) {
                $('.slider').slickPause();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Попробуйте вот так

Comment: не работает(. Если это что-то даст, в слайдере 4 слайда

Comment: index == 3, может так(там индексы с нуля вроде - могу ошибаться)

Comment: Я уже ставил даже index == 0, сама функция почему-то не работает.